# Usage of apply in underscore source

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm studying the [annotated source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) of underscore, and I have a quick question on their usage of apply in the _.defer function. In particular, in _.defer, we use apply on the _ object, while in _.delay, we use apply on null. Why can't we use null instead of _ in _.defer since we don't actually use 'this' in either function?

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

//Delays a function for the given number of milliseconds, and then calls it with the arguments supplied.
_.delay = function(func, wait) {
    var args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return setTimeout(function(){
      return func.apply(null, args);
    }, wait);
};

//Defers a function, scheduling it to run after the current call stack has cleared.
_.defer = function(func) {
    return _.delay.apply(_, [func, 1].concat(slice.call(arguments, 1)));
};
```

Comment: *"Why can't we use null instead of _ in _.defer since we don't actually use 'this' in either function?"* We can, but I guess passing `_` makes it more robust for future changes, in case `this` *is* used at some point. Maybe contact the developer directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `delay()` calling `apply()` causes user-supplied function to execute. There is no obvious or documented contract, what `this` should be in the context of this function. Passing `null` as `this` reference makes sense as it simplifies debugging for end-user: errors will be easy to investigate.

On the other hand, in `defer()`, `apply()` is used to call another underscore API method, it is well known and under control of the developer. Using underscore as `this` makes sense in general, as a common rule for the whole library  - it is intuitive,  it is short, and it provides flexibility if needed later.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense